# How to display some details (Content Text, Content Info and Small Icon) in expanded notifications

Tags: android, notifications, expand

I created a notification using the code below:

```
// Prepare intent which is triggered if the notification is selected
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
intent.setClass(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
long[] vibrationPattern = {0, 200, 800, 200, 600, 200, 400, 200, 200, 200, 100, 200, 50, 200, 50, 200, 50, 200, 50, 200};
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Notif title");
inboxStyle.addLine("one ");
inboxStyle.addLine("two");
inboxStyle.addLine("three");
inboxStyle.addLine("four");
inboxStyle.addLine("five");
inboxStyle.addLine("six");
inboxStyle.addLine("seven");


Notification notification = builder
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Notif title")
        .setContentText("notif text")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.email))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.email)
        .setContentInfo("notif content Info")
        .setWhen(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 1000*60+60)
        .setVibrate(vibrationPattern)
        .setStyle(inboxStyle)
        .setContentText("notif text")
        .build();

notificationManager.notify(myNotificationId , notification);
```

And it works...
**But:**
Is it possible to display the fields 3, 4 and 5 from the attached image (**in the expanded notification, not in the contracted one**)? 
( I took the image from:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/local_notifications_in_android/)
[image: Expanded notification]

Comment: I found the answer: one just needs to set the **subText** field with 'setSubText()' method.

Comment: For the expanded view (InboxStyle) it will be _setSummaryText(CharSequence cs)_